# Storing and passing on parameter pack in factory class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write a "factory" class template whose instantiations have variadic constructors which store their arguments in a tuple and later pass on these arguments to the constructors of objects created by the factory.

A minimal example might make it clearer:

```
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

struct Foo
{
  Foo(int arg1, double arg2)
  {}

  // ...
};

template<typename T, typename ...ARGS>
class Factory
{
public:
  Factory(ARGS&&... args)
  : _stored_args(std::make_tuple(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...))
  {}

  std::unique_ptr<T> create()
  { return std::apply(std::make_unique<T>, _stored_args); }

private:
  std::tuple<ARGS...> _stored_args;
};

template<typename T, typename ...ARGS>
std::unique_ptr<Factory<T, ARGS...>> make_factory(ARGS&&... args)
{ return std::make_unique<Factory<T, ARGS...>>(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...); }

int main()
{
  auto foo_factory(make_factory<Foo>(1, 2.0));

  auto foo_ptr(foo_factory->create());

  // ...
}
```

My problem here is that the call to `std::apply` is apparently malformed since both gcc and clang complain along the lines of `no matching function for call to '__invoke'`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you explain what `create` is supposed to do exactly?

Comment: @cigien Return a `unique_ptr` to an object of type `T`. I haven't explained what exatly I use this factory class for but I don't think it's necessary to understand the problem.

Comment: No, I mean, what makes you think you need `apply`? What is the logic for generating a `unique_ptr<T>` from a `tuple<Args...>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is wrap the `std::make_unique` call into a perfect-forwarding lambda:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> create() {
return std::apply(
    [](auto&&... xs) {
        return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...);
    },
    _stored_args);
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7McW6x)

The reason is that `std::make_unique` doesn't only take a `T` template argument, but also `Args...`, which in this case are deduced by fowarding `xs...`. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).